# delete all lines from match line until end include the match line

Tags: sed, rhel

this is the file that we want to delete all lines from  the line that include “`EXPORTER_JAR_PATH`” until end of file

```
more ambari-agent.ini
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific

export EXPORTER_JAR_PATH=/tmp/hgt.yml
[server]
hostname=master.sys65.com
url_port=8440
secured_url_port=8441
connect_retry_delay=10
max_reconnect_retry_delay=30
```

this is my solution to delete the lines from line that include - `EXPORTER_JAR_PATH`  until end

```
sed '1,/EXPORTER_JAR_PATH/!d' ambari-agent.ini
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific

export EXPORTER_JAR_PATH=/tmp/hgt.yml
```

As we can see the line - `Export` `EXPORTER_JAR_PATH=/tmp/hgt.yml`

Still exists , where we are wrong ?

**Expected output**

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/EXPORTER_JAR_PATH/,$d' file
```

This would delete all lines from the first line that contains the substring `EXPORTER_JAR_PATH` to the end of the file (`$` addresses the end of the file), inclusively.

What your command does is to delete all lines that does not fall within the range between line 1 and the line that contains that string, inclusively.  This means that the line that contains the substring `EXPORTER_JAR_PATH` would not be deleted.

Alternatively, as pointed out in comments below by both Paul_Pendant and mosvy,

```
sed -n '/EXPORTER_JAR_PATH/q;p' file
```

which would explicitly, with `p`, print out each line until it reaches the `EXPORTER_JAR_PATH` line where the script would terminate. The line with the string  wouldn't get printed due to the `-n` option disabling the ordinary default output. The benefit of this is that `sed` would not have to read the whole file (it would however not make a drastic difference in this specific case as the file is so short).

The equivalent thing with `awk` would read

```
awk '/EXPORTER_JAR_PATH/ { exit } { print }' file
```

or, shorter,

```
awk '/EXPORTER_JAR_PATH/ { exit }; 1' file
```

Comment: sed '/EXPORTER_JAR_PATH/Q' file does the same, but is a whole lot faster if the trigger is early in the file: it avoids reading the remainder of the file.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I suppose `Q` is a GNU `sed` instruction, right?

Comment: The Q is Gnu extension, because q outputs the pattern space first. Equivalent Posix is sed -n '/calcChain/q; p'

Comment: @Paul_Pedant no need for any GNU exension: `sed -n '/EXPORTER_JAR_PATH/q;p'`

Comment: @mosvy Showed the non-GNU syntax, but the trigger pattern is from my 23MB XML test file. Assumed the exact application is obvious. Timed at 0.148 secs with ,$d and 0.008 with q;p.